# Why did all the comments on my answer vanish so quickly?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

I had a couple of comments under my answer ([this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/498862/21441)), and was about to reply to a comment of the question author when I noticed that the author had accepted the answer and deleted his account. Then, after I hit the *Add Comment* button to submit the reply, I noticed that all the comments vanished.

Why remove the comments so early? Was it assumed that the OP won't ever return to the post to read the reply? Or were the comments somehow deleted automatically when the OP's account was deleted?

Comment: Were all the comments by the OP? If so, they were probably self-deleted.

Comment: @PM2Ring they were mixed with my replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other user in your comment exchange shouldn't have had the privilege of commenting. You happened to be commenting as a moderator was cleaning up.

In the interest of [protecting the privacy of users who can't currently participate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293213/280545), that's probably all that we can say publicly about this event.  Thanks for respecting that.

Comment: I guess this means that the user also should not have had the privilege of asking questions. Shouldn't one then also remove the question?

Comment: Good guess. Because the question attracted a high-quality answer, the question survives. The user in question here did also ask a negatively-scored question with no answers; that one is gone.